# Calling conventions and garbage collection vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pointers, cpu-registers

From a programming standpoint i'd like to think referencing a variable by address is a good way to go, memory wise. And fast at that.

But does this hold true in VB.NET?

I like to reference a variable/"register" like this. 
Main.module.variable = something.

Alternatively one can generate extra registers by feeding variables through the function body.

My question is this, A: Does VB actually optimize referencing registers well, or well enough to make it fast, like a pointer? Or is the virtual machine adding instructions to the pointer slowing it down?
And B: Does feeding variables to the function body allow for better ASM optimization?

Comment: I am voting to close this questions as there are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs. This ***is not a specific programming problem*** rather an opinion... A quick Google search yielded many great hits, [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289513(v=vs.71).aspx) is just one of the many I found.

Comment: It already works that way, variables of a reference type are pointers under the hood that store the address of the object on the GC heap.  Enregistering those variables and optimizing their usage is the job of the optimizer built into the just-in-time compiler, not the vb.net compiler.

Comment: Hans, At the end of the day it's good practice to my mind "to point". Just wanted to make sure this holds true at a lower level, since it's managed code. Else I may want to refer to another language for the math.

Comment: `Else I may want to refer to another language for the math` what's that supposed to mean? Give an example as I am interested by your thought's...

Comment: SIMD or something like Fortran would be nice. Altho im not really familiar with Fortran.